Are lawyers allowed to stall if their client wants it?
Say a terminally ill person sues someone. That someone (and their lawyers) knows they're likely to lose any case, but also knows that the plaintiff is going to die soon, so they instruct their lawyers to stall as much as they can. This could e.g. involve sending a "give me two weeks to discuss this with my client" every time there is a communication between the parties.
Are their lawyers allowed to do this? If the law is silent on this, are there any codes of conduct that might prohibit this?

Lawyers have a duty to uphold to two groups. One is their client. And the other is to the court.
Lawyers are not supposed to unreasonable delay or impede a case. They are supposed to represent their client diligently and timely. Failing to do so can lead to a case being dismissed due to the attorneys lack of action.
~New York Civil Practice Law and Rules Section 3216: “where a party unreasonably neglects to proceed generally in an action or otherwise delays in the prosecution thereof against any party who may be liable to a separate judgment, or unreasonably fails to serve and file a note of issue, the court, on its own initiative or upon motion, with notice to the parties, may dismiss the party’s pleading on terms.”~
But of course, it's also wrong for a lawyer to steamroll a case just to get it out of the way, if it hurts their own client. Delays to think about it, run out a clock, or other strategies are allowed. Following the letter of the law allowing for postponements can't be held against an attorney. Unless it po's the judge and they are told to hurry it along. And even then, missed deadlines can be excused and winked away. Stalling as a tactic is allowed as long as you don't jump on a table and yell at the judge that you are stalling as a tactic. It's also expected as part of your duty to vigorously represent your client.
In the end it's a balancing act of following the rules and taking a mile when you are allowed to, when it's in your interests and not abusing the rules. See the new York bar forum analysis of the situation from the other side of the table https://nysba.org/opposing-counsel-keep-stalling-what-can-i-do/

Why do you think dead people can’t sue?
A chose in action is generally inheritable, so if the party to the lawsuit dies, the estate keeps it going for the benefit of the beneficiaries. One exception is that actions for defamation die with the defamed.
So, stalling until they die is not a viable strategy.

It's just an example. Could always take another example, e.g. two divorcees both want custody of their child. One parent currently has custody, so they're happy to stall while the other parent wants access to the child. Something like that.

Or maybe one person wants to stall because of an upcoming election and they think if so-and-so wins the election then they'll be released.
